# A function to remove white space and punctuation from a character array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a function that takes in an array of characters with a string, for example ENCRYPT THIS MESSAGE. I have read a few other topics on this site about people doing the same thing but none of the answers worked for me. So I tried to implement a function that takes in the character array and returns a new character array without spaces or punctuation. Here is the function I have so far:

```
  void RemovePunct(char old_String[], char new_String[]){
        for (int i = 0; i != 50; i++)
        {
        if(isspace(old_String[i])==true) continue;
        if(ispunct(old_String[i])==true) continue;
                if(isalnum(old_String[i])) new_String[i] = old_String[i]; 
        }
        return;
}
```

When I run the example string through this function it returns "ENCRYPTSTHIS▒MESSAGEE", "ENCRYPTTHIS▒MESSAGE", "ENCRYPTTHIS▒MESSAGEE", or some similar variation with extra letters or special characters. Sometimes it removes one space successfully but the other space is always a letter or some weird character. Anyone have any ideas what is wrong with this function or how to make it work successfully?

---

EDIT: I added the second index and initilized the arryay, before populating it with the string, to all periods and the function worked as intended.

Comment: You have two strings and one index. This might work ok in porn but not in your code.

Comment: are there any restrictions that prevent usage of std::regex? ex: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace, suits your needs

Comment: regex feels over kill. Simple `std::remove_if` is enough for simple filtering task. [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

Comment: Thanks for the cheeky response Captian-Obvlious had a good chuckle and realized my silly mistake :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use different iterator for new string.
By using "i" across both old and new, your new strings have uninitialized values for characters that are spaces/punctuations in old string

```
void RemovePunct(char old_String[], char new_String[]){
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i != 50; i++)
        {
        if(isspace(old_String[i])==true) continue;
        if(ispunct(old_String[i])==true) continue;
                if(isalnum(old_String[i])) new_String[j++] = old_String[i]; 
        }
        return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked, but now I have a few extra characters on the end of the string. How do you recommend checking that it is the end of the string?

Comment: Terminate the new string with `new_String[j] = 0` and don't forget to add bounds checking - pass the buffer length to `RemovePunct` and make sure you only access or change memory you are supposed to. You should also check for the terminator in the source string.

Comment: that's because you are not doing new_string[j++]='\0'; before return.